# Pixma TS6052 scan error only with 1200 DPI

Tags: printing, display-resolution, scanner, canon

I installed Pixma TS6052 on a Kubuntu 20.04 system and use Skanlite for scanning. The scanner is capable to scan up to 1200 DPI.

When I scan with 300 DPI it goes fast and everthing is OK. When I scan with 600 or even 1200 DPI the scanner is woking even if it lasts of course a bit longer. But then when the scanner is ready skanlite brings an error message "inalid argument". This is only at 600 or 1200 DPI. 300 DPI is fine.

Can somebody help to fix it? I use official scanner driver from Canon.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing gscan2pdf.  And add the ppa for sane stable. [https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git?field.series_filter=focal](https://launchpad.net/%7Erolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git?field.series_filter=focal)

And install the sane-backends.  If gscan2pdf can't do it then report back.

Comment: I installed the tool. At any resolution i get this "gscan2pdf: sane_start: Invalid argument". Is there any sane packgage missing?

Comment: Is the scanner wireless?  Have you installed the printer locally through System Settings?  If not install the scanner using the normal way through printers in system settings.  This may bring in the connection you need.